# SAGA library is not visible in Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis-3, ubuntu, saga, ubuntugis

The screenshot of `Options > Processing`

[image: logo]

I have SAGA plugin activated in my QGIS 3.8 on a Ubuntu 18 LTS machine. However, it does not show up in my Processing Toolbox.

Could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Can you try start QGIS with new profile? Sometimes it's help.

Comment: Because you also need to install SAGA.

Comment: As @xunilk says - check that saga is installed, check that QGIS is looking for the executables in the right place.  You might need symbolic links or to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

Check that saga is installed, in a command prompt try:

```
saga_cmd -V
```

Otherwise install using:

```
sudo apt install saga libsaga libsaga-api-2.3.1 libsaga-dev python-saga saga-common
```

If it is installed, you need to check that QGIS can find the executables.  The log in QGIS should show what commands have failed.